# Django Admin to Access all Database Tables

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

I have many csv files which I need to use them in my Django App and also edit their values by admin.this is what I tried and failed :
In my Django App,I have 2 models for example "`City`" and "`Country`" and a sqlite3 database for example `testDB`.
I registered my 2 models in admin.py file so that admin can add/edit/remove  City and Country records.
But in that database(`testDB`), I have also other tables which created using sqlite commands(`create table <table_name>`) and I don't have models for those[because thos tables created from a csv file].
But I want admin to have access the 3rd table(which is not created by django but sqlite shell command), in admin panel just like my two models.
**Is there a way to do that????**
If not, what should I do to solve my problem described in first 2 lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your db table into django model using

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

And after registering this new created model you can edit/add new values to your table.

You can find more details here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models